# Why does this "after_create" function not initialize default values into my database?

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

**Background/Goal** 
I'm trying to create a study prep website and as part of it I would like to initialize a database labelled "Topic" with some default values. The contents of this table are just meant to be initialized once when the database is first created. I'm using Flask and SQLAlchemy for this project.

**The Problem** 
I've tried to achieve this by defining a function like so (Note: The "..." mark pieces of code present which I believe aren't very relevant to this problem. If you feel like I'm likely leaving out something important, please inform me)

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "hwiu2222"
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = f"sqlite:///{DB_NAME}"
    db.init_app(app)

    ...

    from .models import User, Topic

    create_database(app)

    ...

    @listens_for(Topic.__table__, "after_create")
    def insert_topics(*args, **kwargs):
        topics = (genfromtxt("src/static/topics.csv", delimiter=',', skip_header=1, dtype=None)).tolist()
        for topic in topics:
            new_topic = Topic(title=topic[0], subject=topic[1], level=topic[2])
            db.session.add(new_topic)
        db.session.commit()

    return app

def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists("CIE Website/" + DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app=app)
```

To clarify, this "create_app" function is located in an **init** file in my directory and is called within a separate main python script.

```
from src import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This code runs just fine and I'm able to open my website without any errors, but the problem is that the default values I wanted to be initialized don't actually get initialized. My "Topic" table just remains empty.

**What I've Tried** 
So what I assume is going wrong is that the "insert_topics" function is not getting called for whatever reason. To try and fix this I've attempted to simply relocate said function, such as to before the "create_database" call or within my main script after calling the "create_app" function, but all of that just results in the same error (There's even more to this error message, but it's quite long and I'm not sure how important the other information is, so I'm only including this ending statement for now).

```
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
```

Now, all of this stuff is still very much new to me so what I assume to be going wrong may be completely off the mark. It's also possible that I'm overlooking some glaring mistake that's causing all of this. For example, there could be something wrong with the "insert_topics" function itself. Regardless, I hope that one of you will be able to help me figure this out.

P.S.
I apologize in advance for any mistakes I may have made in writing this quesiton. It's my first time doing anything like this.

Comment: You need to create an [application context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/appcontext/#the-application-context)  (and probably declare the listener before calling create_database)

Comment: Thank you! Looks like that's what was missing from my code.